# Overwrite unstaged commits due to gitattributes eol settings

Tags: git, eol, gitattributes

I have a fork that has automatic eol changes on cloning due to .gitattributes. This is fixed in upstream. I would like to merge upstream into my master; however, I am unable to get rid of these unstaged changes. I can't reset, and I can't stash them unless I am missing something. How do I merge upstream/master into master overwriting these local unstaged "changes"?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can try

```
git reset --hard
```

to get rid of any changes in the working dir and the index. Now you should be able to

```
git merge --ff-only upstream/branchname
```

If for some reason the git attributes make it seem like there are changes and it won't work, try

```
git push . upstream/yourbranch:yourbranch
```

If this works, you should be in a headless state. IE, your current commit is not being tracked by any branch.

```
git checkout yourbranch
```

should get you to the updated one now. If the attributes are still causing you grief, add the `--force` option to the checkout.

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried this for my problem and the reset --hard did get rid of the offending file.